# Why do we finish reading the Torah on Simchat Torah and not Shavuot?

Tags: parsha-torah-portion, simchat-torah

Why do we finish/restart reading the Torah on the 22nd of Tishrei (Simchat Torah)? Wouldn't it make more sense to align our Torah reading cycle with Shavuot, the anniversary of receiving the Torah?